# immutable.js updating/setting complicated Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Lets say I have a this Immutable Map:

```
var testing = Immutable.fromJS({
  state: {
    name: 'secret',
    elements: [
      {
        id: 678,
        name: 'first'
      },
      {
        id: 689,
        name: 'first'
      },
      {
        id: 699,
        name: 'first'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Changing the name in state is very easy:

```
testing.setIn(['state', 'name'], 'new name')
```

But how can I update the name on one of the `elements`?

If I would new the index of the element I could do this:

```
testing.setIn(['state', 'elements', 1, 'name'], 'new element index 1 name')
```

Ive been wondering if it is possible to inject some sort of filter inside of the `keyPath` array so I can match record to update based on id?

```
testing.setIn(['state', 'elements', (something here that will pick right record based on id passed here), 'name'], 'new element index 1 name')
```

aka:

```
testing.setIn(['state', 'elements', MAGIC(id: 689), 'name'], 'new element index 1 name')
```

I can look for the index using the findIndex() function and add it my self but I have been wondering i there is a more conscious way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might do it like this:

```
testing.getIn(['state', 'elements'])
  .map(element => element.get('id') === myId ? 
    element.update('name', name => 'New Name') : 
    element);
```

The idea being that you map over the elements and only update the name of the one that passes the ternary operator.

I'm not aware of anything like you describe above in `Immutable`.